# angular6: How to display value of form

Tags: angular, forms, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I want to display only information from the form that controlname is in myObject.

```
this.form = this.FormBuilder.group({
  lname:[null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  fname: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  phone:[null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  id:[null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  age:[null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
});
```

**I only want to display the values ​​in this object**

```
this.myObject = {0:"id", 1:"fname", 2:"lname"}



for (var val in this.myObject ) {
console.log(this.form.value.myObject [val] )

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
for(let item in this.myObject){
      console.log(this.form.controls[this.myObject[item]].value) 
      console.log(this.form.get(this.myObject[item]).value) // or
      console.log(this.form.value[this.myObject[item]]) // or
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside for loop:
`this.form.get(val).value`

`FormGroup.get(controllerName: string)` returns `AbstractController`